# How do you efficiently compute a bijective base-k numeral (and/or its inverse) in R or any other freely-available programming language?

Tags: numbers, symbols, enumeration, representation, bijection

Although *this question already has partial answers on StackOverflow*, those answers are not associated with questions that have the proper name of the process / concept ([bijective (base-k) numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration)) in the title or among the tags. I anticipate that many answers will essentially be links to those existing answers.

This question is partially answered in [How to list from A to Z in PHP, and then on to AA, AB, AC, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958518/how-to-list-from-a-to-z-in-php-and-then-on-to-aa-ab-ac-etc)

Bijective base-26 numeration can be used to compute column ID's in the scheme used in many spreadsheet programs, such as LibreOffice [Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), Lotus-123, [VisiCalc](https://web.archive.org/web/20160208215714/http://danbricklin.com/visicalc.htm)(I think), [ProCalc 3D](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=procalc+3d), and others.

The following is R *pseudocode* (I'm not *yet* including the "raw" R code for the dependencies) for one solution. The return is an integer vector (*little endian*) whose elements are conceptually mapped to the arbitrary symbols used for the representation of the bijective numeration:

```
bijective.numeral <- function(n, symbols=26L) {
    if (!is_among.contiguous.integers(n)) return (NULL)
    if (n  < 0) return(iNA)
    if (n == 0) return(integer())
    intermediate <- pseudo.log(n, symbols) %|% integer
            # PREALLOCATE A VECTOR LONG ENOUGH FOR THE RESULT
    m <- 0L
    while (n) {
        m <- 1L + m
        intermediate[[m]] <- 1:symbols %[mod% n
        n <- n %|% pred %/% symbols }
    intermediate[1:m] }

LETTERS[16384 %|% bijective.numeral] %|% rev %|% `%//%`

# [1] "XFD"
```

Comment: I agree with the several related questions / answers not referencing the concept properly, but what are you exactly asking here? You seem to already have a working piece of code. Is it about efficiency? If so how efficient a solution are you looking for?

Comment: Well, in my pseudocode, I use a logarithm to estimate how many places are needed for the result. The example provided by @Cosine uses string, which I'm guessing (not super familiar with Javascript) is dynamically allocated or over-allocated. Seems like there are some opportunities for trading off a little storage for some speed. Maybe always allocate enough space for the base-2 case? I wonder if those spreadsheet programs use a precalculated lookup table. One source reports VisiCalc had 63 columns, which would not be too bad for a look-up table, even in the late '70's (about 128 bytes).

Comment: I was pointing out that I think the question would benefit (and potentially get more answers) from being more focused and making clear what particular, single problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know R, but in case it helps, this is the implementation of bijective numeration that i just wrote in javascript:

```
function bijectiveString(m, k) {
  if (m == 0) {
      return [];
  }
  let string = [];
  function f(x) {
    return Math.ceil(x) - 1;
  }
  let qn = f(m / k); // q0
  string.push(m - qn * k); // a0
  while (qn != 0) {
    let qnInc = f(qn / k);
    let anInc = qn - qnInc*k;
    string.push(anInc);
    qn = qnInc;
  }
  return string.reverse();
}
```