# In PHP why does range a-Z and a for loop applied to the alphabet produce different characters?

Tags: php, loops, ascii

I noticed there is two different behaviors in PHP when we increment the alphabet:

**Range:**

```
range('a', 'Z');
```

**output:**

```
["a","`", "_", "^", "]","\", "[","Z"]
```

Which correspond to the ASCII table and make sense to me.

But when we increment with a **for loop:**

```
$letters = [];
for($i = 'a'; $i !== 'Z'; $i++){
    $letters[] = $i;
}
```

**output:**

```
[ "a", "b", "c", "d", ..., "x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", ...]
```

Why is php suddenly stuck with the letters 'a-z' instead of using the ASCII table?

And how does work the range method for not using this behavior?

Comment: fixed, I did copy/paste the wrong output from my tests

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14278603/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations
>   on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a =
>   'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into
>   '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that
>   character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so
>   only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are
>   supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no
>   effect, the original string is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, but this not really answering my question: Why is `range` doesn't return 'AA' too? Why is this different?

Comment: `AA` is a string consisting of 2 single-byte characters.

Comment: Because the Range() function is "plugged" on the ASCII table and the increment operator is not. There's no other answer. It is a design choice from PHP developpers.

Comment: From the range manual: _Note:

Character sequence values are limited to a length of one. If a length greater than one is entered, only the first character is used._

Comment: Thanks Thomas G! Maybe one day, I will know what the reasons behind it.

Comment: Advice: sometimes you have to not think too much about things and just  accept them as they are

Comment: mickmackusa: my question is not: Why it's doesn't work, but why it works like that.