# Listing alphabets a to z only produces the first letter a

Tags: php

I have the following code where I try to print alphabets from a to z in the first column. but I only get the letter "a" is printed through the entire column.

```
function print_table_tb ($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT stata,statb,statc FROM dbA";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table class='tbr' id='tb$id'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data = array_reduce($row, function($carry, $value) {
                $carry[] = "<td dbval='{$value}'>{$value}</td>";
                return $carry;
            }, []);

            $range = range('a', 'z');
            $i = 0;

            echo '<tr><td class="tbe">'.$range[$i++ % 26].'</td>'. implode('', $data) . "</tr>\n" ;

        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? thanks for your help! My question is different. I don't seek a solution to get alphabetical listing, I have the solution, but I couldn't fix an error.

I tried this but it doesn't work either.

```
function print_table_tb ($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT stata,statb,statc FROM dbA";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        $range = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
        $i = 0;

        echo "<table class='tbr' id='tb$id'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data = array_reduce($row, function($carry, $value) {
                $carry[] = "<td dbval='{$value}'>{$value}</td>";
                return $carry;
            }, []);


            echo '<tr><td class="tbe">' . $range[$i] . '</td>'
                . implode('', $data) . "</tr>\n" ;
            $i++;    
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP range() from A to ZZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278603/php-range-from-a-to-zz)

Comment: If you use proper indenting, you'll see that you're defining $range and $i within your while loop, so you'll only ever get the first entry. I've fixed the formatting in your post so that you can see it better.

Comment: U want to have 26 rows in your html table and the last one will be with z character, right? What if there will be more then 26 rows in database?

Comment: yes, that's right. Alphabetical listing starts over from "a" again.

Comment: @aynber, I tried your suggestion but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Why should I change  $i++ % 26? it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$range = range('a', 'z');
 $i = 0;  
 echo "<table class='tbr' id='tb$id'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data = array_reduce($row, function($carry, $value) {
            $carry[] = "<td dbval='{$value}'>{$value}</td>";
            return $carry;
        }, []);
        $temp = ($i % 26);
        $i++;
        echo '<tr><td class="tbe">'.$range[$temp].'</td>'. implode('', $data) . "</tr>\n" ;

  }
```

Comment: I have updated my code just check it once it's work for you

Comment: thanks, I tried the new code. this time I get only "b"s instead of  "a"s.

Comment: can you check to echo $i  is the increment properly or not so we can find the problem?

Comment: When $i=0, it prints b, when $i=1, it prints c  etc with the new code. The Increment works properly in the original code I posted too actually.

Comment: Place $i++ after the temp veriable

Comment: I used $i++ as in your suggestion, but still no luck.